# terraform import throws "Index value required" error for a string key value

Tags: terraform

This is what it would look like in the state file if it is created from the scratch by terraform:

```
{
  "module": "module.rds",
  "mode": "managed",
  "type": "aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter",
  "name": "rds_logs_delivery",
  "each": "map",
  "provider": "provider.aws",
  "instances": [
    {
      "index_key": "prod-service-master.audit",
      "schema_version": 0,
      "attributes": {
        "destination_arn": "arn:aws:firehose:us-east-5:9999999999:deliverystream/prod-rds-logs",
        "distribution": "ByLogStream",
        "filter_pattern": "",
        "id": "cwlsf-9999999999",
        "log_group_name": "/aws/rds/instance/prod-service-master/audit",
        "name": "rds-logs-delivery-prod-service-master",
        "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::9999999999:role/cloudwatch-logs-to-kinesis"
      },
      "private": "abcdefg",
      "depends_on": [
        "data.aws_caller_identity.current",
        "data.aws_partition.current",
        "data.terraform_remote_state.kinesis_delivery_stream"
      ]
    },
```

For some reasons I need to import this into another tf state file. So I ran this command:

```
 terraform import module.rds.aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter.rds_logs_delivery["prod-service-reports.audit"] rds-logs-delivery-prod-service-master
```

I got this error:

```
Error: Index value required

  on <import-address> line 1:
   1: module.rds.aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter.rds_logs_delivery[prod-service-reports.audit]

Index brackets must contain either a literal number or a literal string.
```

How can I fix it? I have tried

1. replace double quote with single quote, and
2. no quote

but I still get the same error.

Comment: That index you are using does look like a variable instead of a literal. What does the resource look like so we know how it is being iterated upon?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I have the same problem, trying to import a ressource with a for_each in it so I must refer to the isntance, but the import keeps stripping away the " , even with an escaped character

Answer (score 49):

As suggested by [@JamesK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/749568/jamesk) in this answer above is only the solution if you are using Linux or more specifically bash or Git Bash under Windows.

The solution for PowerShell is the following:

```
terraform import resource[\`"prod-service-reports.audit\`"] ...
```

Thanks to the answer [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/26664#issuecomment-718912702) :)

Answer (score 36):

You need to escape the quotes. As in,

```
terraform import   module.rds.aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter.rds_logs_delivery[\"prod-service-reports.audit\"] rds-logs-delivery-prod-service-master
```

Answer (score 21):

i found you need to do something like this is powershell core 7

```
terraform state rm 'resource[\"thing\"]'
```

this is doc'd with an example over at https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/state/show#example-show-a-resource-configured-with-for_each

Update 2023-01, dunno what's changed but in PS7 latest and TF latest i haven't needed the \ anymore despite the docs saying i do, this seems to work now

```
terraform state rm 'resource["thing"]'
```

Comment: You're repeating what previous answers have already provided.

Comment: @Lethargos not i'm not, one answer had backticks that didn't work for me at all, another failed to wrap in single quotes and didn't work for me at all.

Comment: The answer from Artiom on the 6 July 2021 looks quite clear to me though.

Comment: @Lethargos but yet it didn't work because of the missing single quotes

Comment: @Lethargos just hit this again, and none of the other answers worked, only this one worked, which is distinctively different

Comment: Thanks for this, Chris. I need this syntax as the others did not work.

Comment: I agree , the single quotes is mandatory.  I tested in Windows, Azure RM, PS 7, Terraform V1.3 and VSCode. Also upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 5):

1. Import into Resource configured with "**count**"

   *terraform import 'aws_instance.example[0]' aws-resource-id*
2. Import into Resource configured with "**for_each**"

- **Linux, Mac OS, and UNIX**

  *terraform import 'aws_instance.example["ample"]' aws-resource-id*
- **VSCode n Powershell**

  *terraform import 'aws_instance.example[\"ample\"]' aws-resource-id*
- **cmd**

  *terraform import aws_instance.exapmle["ample"] aws-resource-id*

Here are more examples of terraform import [CLICK HERE](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/import)

Answer (score 4):

Adding my 50 cents to this old thread, if you are running the command from a PowerShell session, the character to escape quotes is backtick: `

Example:

> terraform import   module.rds.aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter.rds_logs_delivery[`"prod-service-reports.audit`"] rds-logs-delivery-prod-service-master